# React Native Navigation v5 redirect after Login to previous screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I have a product screen and an "Add to Cart" button. When the user press the button, I need to check if the user is authenticated or not. If not, then I want to navigate them to Login Screen. **However, after successful login how can I redirect this user to the product screen that they were in before?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just send a navigation params from cart to login. Then after login check if it came from cart using the navigation or route params, if it so then call `navigation.goBack()` or `navigation.navigate('Cart')`